# Duplicate entries in dropdown from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Okay so I'm new to mySQL.  I'm sorry this is a very novice question.  Essentially I have two tables, Associates, and keys.
The content is as follows:

**associates:**
id,
department,
associate,
date_added

**keys:**
id,
key_name,
date_added,

my code to make my dropdown is as follows:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('hostname', 'user', 'Password');
mysql_select_db('log');

$key_fetch = "SELECT `associates`.`department`,`associates`.`associate`,`keys`.`key_name` FROM associates , `keys` ORDER BY `key_name` DESC";
$results = mysql_query($key_fetch);

echo "<select name='key_name' size='5'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['key_name'] . "'>" . $row['key_name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The problem is I only have 5 keys and I have ten associates, and this creates duplicates in my dropdown and I can't fix it with SELECT DISTINCT, and I'm not too sure what else to try.

Comment: First you should stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Instead you should either be using `mysqli_*` or look into `PDO`. Second, why not just have two separate queries?

Comment: so there is no relationship between assoc and keys. You get a cartesian product of 50 rows

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @ElefantPhace I will look into mysqli_, I was trying to put a single block of code because I need to add a second and third dropdown list later in the same page.  Essentially I need to build a key list that will be assigned to a department and associate and save that to the database.

Comment: no @Drew I have somewhat of a CMS page that will allow to add an associate or keys when needed. That's why I have two tables, the key section is rarely updated.

Comment: look at `$key_fetch`. That is a `cartesian product`, `cross join`. There is no relationship between the two tables, other than, hey db engine, give me every permutation. I could be missing something and dense

Comment: Thanks @Drew I will look into cartesian product and cross join and see if I come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To visualize cartesian product based on above Q comments.

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    stuff1 varchar(50) not null
);
insert t1 (stuff1) values ('111.1'),('111.2'),('111.3');

create table t2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    stuff2 varchar(50) not null
);
insert t2 (stuff2) values ('222.1'),('222.2'),('222.3');
```

### A: an explicit Join

```
select t1.id,t1.stuff1,t2.stuff2 
from t1 
join t2 
on t2.id=t1.id;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | stuff1 | stuff2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 111.1  | 222.1  |
|  2 | 111.2  | 222.2  |
|  3 | 111.3  | 222.3  |
+----+--------+--------+
```

### B: An old-style cartesian product

```
select t1.id,t1.stuff1,t2.stuff2 
from t1,t2;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | stuff1 | stuff2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | 111.1  | 222.1  |
|  2 | 111.2  | 222.1  |
|  3 | 111.3  | 222.1  |
|  1 | 111.1  | 222.2  |
|  2 | 111.2  | 222.2  |
|  3 | 111.3  | 222.2  |
|  1 | 111.1  | 222.3  |
|  2 | 111.2  | 222.3  |
|  3 | 111.3  | 222.3  |
+----+--------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### C: Cross join, same output as B:

```
select t1.id,t1.stuff1,t2.stuff2 
from t1 cross join t2
```

So, your output, as I see it, is like B, 50 rows.

Comment: Thanks @Drew this really helped put it into perspective.  I'm looking at options to create these dropdowns.

Comment: No problem Red. Good luck with those dropdowns ! Better you than me.